# Swiss travel pass - Where to buy and how to use?

Tags: trains, tickets, switzerland

I'm from Brazil and I will spend a couple of weeks in Switzerland.
I saw there are many questions about the Swiss Travel Pass but it seems there are no questions or answers regarding how to get it and how to use it.

1. Can I buy the Swiss Travel Pass at the Swiss airport or train station (I will arrive at Zurich)?
2. If yes, how long it will take to buy it? I mean, will it be easy as get there, ask for the pass, pay and get out (something like a few minutes transaction) or would it be a huge amount of effort that takes a couple of hours?
3. What kind of papers do I need to buy it? Is a passport enough?
4. Once I have it, how do I use it to buy the actual train tickets? Just ask for the ticket to the person selling the tickets and present the pass during the purchase?
5. If I decide to buy it online, do I need to print something and get the actual pass at some place? Or does the printed piece have the validity of the actual pass?

I know there are many questions here, but the are all in the same "package" of how to use the pass.

Here are the links I found about the pass but nothing about how to get/use it:
[Official website](https://www.swiss-pass.ch/swiss-pass/)

Comment: Don't know all the answers to your questions, but once you have the pass, that is your ticket. Just get on the train and show the pass.

Comment: Please don't overlook that the Pass doubles as a Museum Pass on days of validity, covering hundreds of museums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can pick up the Swiss Travel Pass at the airport when pre-ordered. It can also be bought at [any major railway station](https://help.myswitzerland.com/hc/en-us/articles/213634385-Where-can-I-buy-a-Swiss-Travel-Pass-a-Swiss-Transfer-Ticket-or-a-Swiss-Family-Card-) and the tourist office in Zurich, and ordered online and printed at home. For Brazil, the delivery options vary between CHF 15 and 25 (this information can be found under 'delivery options' when going through the order process).
2. I do not know the counter at the airport. However, as this is mainly about picking up your pass, it mostly depends on the queue time. If you order for printing at home, you will not have to go to any counter.
3. [This FAQ entry](https://help.myswitzerland.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001474909-Where-and-how-do-I-have-to-get-my-tickets-validated-) indicates that the ticket will be linked to your passport number.
4. The Swiss Travel Pass **is** your ticket. [It includes all travel on regular trains, buses and boats](https://help.myswitzerland.com/hc/en-us/articles/213124709-Which-services-does-the-Swiss-Travel-Pass-include-).
5. When buying online, you will print out your Swiss Travel Pass at home, which serves as the actual, valid ticket.

Here you will find more general info on the [Swiss Travel Pass](https://www.sbb.ch/en/leisure-holidays/travel-in-switzerland/international-guests/swiss-travel-pass.html), such as the [area of validity (link to PDF)](https://www.sbb.ch/content/dam/sbb/de/infotexte/uebersichtskarte-sts.pdf).

Please also study the [FAQ](https://help.myswitzerland.com/hc/en-us/sections/115000769685-Tickets) if you encounter more questions and also consider the [following limitations](https://www.myswitzerland.com/en-ch/rechtliche-hinweise-swiss-travel-system.html) when buying the Swiss Travel Pass.

Enjoy your visit to Switzerland!